# How do I add structure logging to my Python library?

Tags: python

I have a Python library which I want to use structured logging for. I've been targeting `python-json-logger`, which automatically converts a `dict` passed to the `extra` kwarg of a logger to JSON:

```
In [1]: import logging

In [2]: from pythonjsonlogger import jsonlogger

In [3]: logger = logging.getLogger()

In [4]: handler = logging.StreamHandler()

In [5]: formatter = jsonlogger.JsonFormatter()

In [6]: handler.setFormatter(formatter)

In [7]: logger.addHandler(handler)

In [8]: logger.warning("test", extra={"username": "jashugan"})
{"message": "test", "username": "jashugan"}
```

This means that if the application using my library would like JSON-formatted logs, they can configure their logger like above.

However, if the application using my library doesn't do any configuration, then the information I'm storing in `extra` gets completely lost:

```
In [1]: import logging

In [2]: logger = logging.getLogger()

In [3]: logger.warning("test", extra={"username": "jashugan"})
test
```

Is there a way that I could use `extra` to create structured logs and have the information show up automatically if the application doesn't configure logging to render it specifically?

Comment: dont do logging inside library, in the application you need to do logging

Comment: A library has no business deciding for its consumers how or where they want to see logs. See https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#configuring-logging-for-a-library

Comment: @temmo **Do** log in your library, but **do not** configure the logging. Especially not the loggers outside of the scope of your library.

Comment: @KlausD. yes have log in library, but on application level dont set library logs in it

Comment: I totally agree; log configuration belongs in the application. I'm not trying to configure logging in my library. I'm trying to write structured logs so that they application, if they choose to do so, can write JSON-formatted logs.